# 301 Redirect Loop accessing Nova after migrating to Linux Server

Tags: laravel-nova

My Laravel application and Nova are working fine on my local Windows 7 PC development environment running under XAMPP. Not using SSL under this environment.

But after migrating the application to the Linux Server runnning EasyApache WHM/Cpanel  with SSL.

Nova throws a redirection loop both before and after login (login page is only accessible by entering  /nova/login directly).

The 301 redirects appears to be alternating between /nova and /nova/

```
https://app.mydomain.com/nova
301 Moved Permanently
https://app.mydomain.com/nova/
301 Moved Permanently
https://app.mydomain.com/nova
301 Moved Permanently
https://app.mydomain.com/nova/
301 Moved Permanently
https://app.mydomain.com/nova
301 Moved Permanently
https://app.mydomain.com/nova/
301 Moved Permanently
https://app.mydomain.com/nova
301 Moved Permanently
https://app.mydomain.com/nova/

etc...
```

HTTP Headers

```
>>> https://app.mydomain.com/nova

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Sun, 01 Sep 2019 20:31:33 GMT
Server: Apache
Location:   https://app.mydomain.com/nova/
Content-Length: 242
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

>>> https://app.mydomain.com/nova/

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Sun, 01 Sep 2019 20:31:33 GMT
Server: Apache
Location:   https://app.mydomain.com/nova
Content-Length: 241
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

>>> https://app.mydomain.com/nova

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Sun, 01 Sep 2019 20:31:34 GMT
Server: Apache
Location:   https://app.mydomain.com/nova/
Content-Length: 242
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

>>> https://app.mydomain.com/nova/

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Sun, 01 Sep 2019 20:31:35 GMT
Server: Apache
Location:   https://app.mydomain.com/nova
Content-Length: 241
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1


>>> https://app.mydomain.com/nova

> --------------------------------------------
> 301 Moved Permanently
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Sun, 01 Sep 2019 20:31:35 GMT
Server: Apache
Location:   https://app.mydomain.com/nova/
Content-Length: 242
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

etc etc
```

Only a standard CPANEL .htaccess file is used

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>

</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>

</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Really not sure where else to look.  I have run: php artisan cache:clear, config:cache, config:clear, view:clear

Is this a known bug with Nova?  Any assistance would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the default .htaccess created by  Cpanel on EasyApache 4. Note I commented out the first two lines after Rewrite Engine on and replaced them with the two lines below:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

   # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
   # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>

</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>

</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```